How to create a Vec of instances of a struct using const generics, while still using methods depending on the value of the generic in Rust?
I am trying to learn some Rust by creating a neural network from scratch.
I started by defining a Matrix struct using const generics in order to check for matrix size at compile time when performing operations such as matrix addition or multiplication.
I then use this Matrix struct in order to define another struct, DenseLayer, again using const generics for the size (number of synapses entering and leaving the layer).
I then want to create a Network struct with a "layers" field containing a Vec of DenseLayers. However, the size of each of these layers can be different.
I have read the Rust book section about the use of dyn Trait in order to have different instances of a generic struct that all implement Trait, but I am not sure how to define that trait (You can find a stub of a LayerTrait in layer.rs, but it obviously gives errors).
I need to still be able to access the values of the const generics used in the definition of a DenseLayer instance, as I use it in the new and forward methods (and others I will have to implement later on).
Is there a way to do what I'm aiming to do? I'm quite new to Rust, so there might well be a simple workaround I haven't thought of.
If not, would there still be another way to make the matrix size check at compile-time?
Or does it not make sense at all to do it the way I'm trying to do it?
Here is the code I have written so far (divided into files matrix.rs, layer.rs and network.rs):
matrix.rs
use std::ops::{Add, Mul};

#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq)]
pub struct Matrix<const N: usize, const M: usize> {
    data: [[f32; M]; N],
}

impl<const N: usize, const M: usize> Matrix<N, M> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            data: [[0f32; M]; N],
        }
    }

    pub fn from_array(data: [[f32; M]; N]) -> Self {
        Self { data }
    }
}

impl<const N: usize, const M: usize> Add for Matrix<N, M> {
    type Output = Matrix<N, M>;

    fn add(self, rhs: Self) -> Self::Output {
        let mut result = Self::new();
        for i in 0..N {
            for j in 0..M {
                result.data[i][j] = self.data[i][j] + rhs.data[i][j];
            }
        }
        result
    }
}

impl<const N: usize, const M: usize, const P: usize> Mul<Matrix<M, P>> for Matrix<N, M> {
    type Output = Matrix<N, P>;

    fn mul(self, rhs: Matrix<M, P>) -> Self::Output {
        let mut result = Matrix::<N, P>::new();
        for i in 0..N {
            for j in 0..P {
                result.data[i][j] = (0..M)
                    .map(|k| self.data[i][k] * rhs.data[k][j])
                    .fold(0f32, |acc, x| acc + x);
            }
        }
        result
    }
}

layer.rs
use crate::matrix::*;

pub trait LayerTrait {
    fn new(weights: Matrix<OUT, IN>, biases: Matrix<OUT, 1>) -> Self;
    fn forward(&self, input: Matrix<IN, 1>) -> Matrix<OUT, 1>;
}

pub struct DenseLayer<const IN: usize, const OUT: usize> {
    weights: Matrix<OUT, IN>,
    biases: Matrix<OUT, 1>,
}

impl<const IN: usize, const OUT: usize> LayerTrait for DenseLayer<IN, OUT> {
    pub fn new(weights: Matrix<OUT, IN>, biases: Matrix<OUT, 1>) -> Self {
        Self { weights, biases }
    }

    pub fn forward(&self, input: Matrix<IN, 1>) -> Matrix<OUT, 1> {
        (self.weights.clone() * input) + self.biases.clone()
    }
}


network.rs
use crate::layer::*;
use crate::matrix::*;
use std::ops::{Add, Mul};

pub struct Network {
    layers: Vec<Box<dyn LayerTrait>>,
}

impl Network {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self { layers: vec![] }
    }

    pub fn add_layer<const IN: usize, const OUT: usize>(&mut self, layer: Box<dyn LayerTrait>) {
        self.layers.push(layer);
    }

    pub fn forward<const IN: usize, const OUT: usize>(
        &self,
        input: Matrix<IN, 1>,
    ) -> Matrix<OUT, 1> {
        let mut current_output = input;
        for layer in &self.layers {
            current_output = layer.forward(current_output);
        }
        current_output
    }
}

I have tried defining a LayerTrait that would allow using dyn LayerTrait in the definition of Network, but:

if I define it as LayerTrait<const IN: usize, const OUT: usize>, then as far as I understand IN and OUT are constant over all layers, and I get the following errors in network.rs:

"cannot find type IN in this scope" on line 6
"unresolved item provided when a constant was expected" on line 6
"cannot find type OUT in this scope" on line 6


if I define it as LayerTrait, then IN and OUT are undefined in the forward method, but as far as I understand, I need to define forward as a LayerTrait trait method, if I want to call it from the Network struct.


In the network you need to handle matrices of all sizes uniformly - so how do you plan to call new() and forward()?

In order to store multiple differently sized layers in the same vector, then the OUT and IN information must be available at runtime to disambiguate between them.

You will have easier times and save yourself runtime errors if you will erase all size knowledge for the network, handling all layers uniformly as they join the network.

@ChayimFriedman I'm not sure what you mean by "erase all size knowledge for the network". Do you mean keeping it for Matrix and Layer but hiding it from the network? If yes, I can't find a way to do that. Or do you mean deleting the generic const for the Matrix struct and checking for sizes at runtime? If yes then I agree it will definitely be easier but I was going the former way in the aim of avoiding runtime errors by letting the compiler check for matrix sizes. Why would it actually increase the chance of runtime errors?

@PitaJ Yes definitely, but that's where I'm stuck. Is it just not doable or is there a workaround I didn't think of?
